# I get this error while installing scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cmd, pip

When trying to install scikit-learn using cmd, I get the following error :

```
pip install scikit-learn==0.14.1
```

output

```
ERROR: Failed building wheel for scikit-learn
error: legacy-install-failure
```

Comment: you could try to install / upgrade wheel before running the command again with `pip install -U wheel` but also first check if the version of the library supports your version of python https://pypi.org/project/scikit-learn/0.14.1/ this version seems to only support till python3.3

Comment: I already update and upgrade wheel and I use python 3.7

Comment: yeah the pypi page says it only supports till 3.3 so you might have to use a newer version of scikit-learn (anything above 0.20.0 seems to support 3.7

Comment: I installed python versions less than 3.3 but problem not solved and in some versions they didn't support scrip and there are some other issues.

Comment: sorry but i have no idea then :(

the only other 2 things i can think of are either checking the dependency versions required on https://pypi.org/project/scikit-learn/0.14.1/ and making sure you have those versions and if even that doesn't work then maybe just download the package file directly and try installing from that (also i looked at the file for py3.3 they had but its just win32 not win32_amd64 so idk if it even supports 64 bit)